# Как сохранять отдельно каждый файл при изменении файла (событие OnChange)

Tags: c#, события

Имеется метод `OnChange` который реагирует на изменение файла, проблема в том что при изменении программа сохраняет текущее изменение и всё, то есть если создать файл, написать там `123`, а потом дописать `456`, то в итоге будет один файл `123456`, а мне нужно два отдельных `123` и `123456`, не знаю как сделать.

```
private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        Console.WriteLine($"Файл изменен: {e.Name} \r\nДействие произведенное с ним: {e.ChangeType} \r\nПуть до файла: {e.FullPath} \r\nВремя изменения:{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}\r\n");
        string backUpFileName = pathSystem + "\\" + e.Name;
        File.Copy(e.FullPath, backUpFileName, true);
    }
    finally
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать. Дубликат файла до изменения? Можно добавить временную метку в конце названия файла, что бы было понятно что и когда, да и файлы тогда будут не перезаписываться, а создаваться новые.

Comment: Дубликат файла при каждом изменении внутри файла

Comment: А копировать старый файл в новое место, а потом в новый файл записать новые данные пробовали?

Comment: название события `OnChanged` намекает, что к моменту его вызова исходный файл уже был изменен